# Preffered viewPort to dealing with textButton libgdx

Tags: libgdx, viewport

i work with a new game , i have create 2 camera one camera for real world and another (GUI) camera for a static  resolution (800 x 480)

```
private void init () {

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(16,9);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.update();

    cameraGUI = new OrthographicCamera(800,480);
    cameraGUI.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    cameraGUI.update();
```

And i want to use a textButton in my game , so i've create a new stage using a new fitViewPort

```
    fitViewPort=new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    gameController.stage=new Stage(fitViewPort);
```

then i create my textButtons using my bitmap font and i try it on the Desktop , and it's great
[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbpDh.png)

but when i try another device , the position is not the same 
[Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2aAo.png)

then i think for using the cameraGui Width and height for my view port , the font is very bad stretched

any help please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a special camera for GUI, because viewport already has a camera.

Make your viewport width and height fixed, in your case:

```
fitViewPort = new FitViewport(800, 480);
gameController.stage = new Stage(fitViewPort);
```

And then just add actors to stage and draw it just by calling method

```
gameController.stage.draw();
```

**Note:** Remember to add `gameController.stage.getViewport().update(width, height);` in your resize method.

Edit: Using small fixed viewport (800x480 is small) will cause scaling, that is why the font is stretched. For example if you run a 800x480 layout on 1920x1080 display it will be scaled by 225%.

What you can do is generate a font with big size and the set scale to its data fe. `bitmapFont20.getData().setScale(0.5F);` (in this case font is generated by FreeTypeFontGenerator with size 40). Using this trick you will be able to get a great results. The proof is below. It is viewport of `640x360F * (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` scaled to 1920x1080. Font is generated with size 72 and then data scale is set to 0.5F

[image: Method proff]

Here is the same text, but without modified data scale.

[image: Without method]

Comment: There are many cases where a separate camera and viewport for the GUI are appropriate.

Comment: thanks for this Answer , but this doesn't fix my problem , the font is still ugly

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it includes a way to make font scaling look better.

Comment: Thanks again , i try it with some bitmapFont to draw and it's look greate , but how can i use it with textButton , i see the the button.font.getData().setScale(..) doesn't work ,
thanks .

Comment: What I do (and what does work) I change `getData().setScale()` once and then I assign the scaled font to the style `textLabelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(bitmapFont14, Color.WHITE);` where I previously have `parameter.size = 28;
        BitmapFont bitmapFont14 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        bitmapFont14.getData().setScale(0.5F);`

Comment: It seems that in the new version of libgdx ( 1.9.4 and 1.9.5-snapshot ) this method doesn't work , and someone tell me to use button.getLabel().setFontScale(0.5f); and it's work , Big thanks to you , now the font look awesome :)